# React-native-firebase notification in background (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using the react-native-firebase library and I am brainstorming to customize my notifications when they are in the background, I tried to follow the documentation but to no avail, are there native code .java to handle notifications?

Answer (score 0):

To customize the background notifications you can add in the index of your application:

```js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import App from './App'
import { backgroundMessageNotificationHandler } from 'src/common/notifications'

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testApp', () => App)
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask(
  'RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage',
  () => backgroundMessageNotificationHandler)
```

The backgroundMessageNotificationHandler could be something like that:

```js
export const backgroundMessageNotificationHandler = async (message: any) => {
  const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification().android
    .setChannelId(androidNotificationsChannel.channelId)
    .android.setSmallIcon('iconBlackAndWhite')
    .android.setLargeIcon('iconBlackAndWhite')
    .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
    .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
    .setSound('default')
    .setTitle(message.data.title)
    .setBody(message.data.body)
    .setData(message.data)

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    createChannel()
  }

  firebase.notifications().displayNotification(localNotification)

  return Promise.resolve()
}
```

Remember to follow the steps to setting up the build.gralde, MainActivity and AndroidManifest. You can follow the steps specified in the following post:

[React-Native Android Push Notification via Firebase](https://medium.com/ltunes/react-native-android-push-notification-via-firebase-6451263b3ffb)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added the methods I created my Channel but still unsuccessful, when I send my notifications the title and body still remain the same.